# fla file, where is the code (AS)

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I have an an fla file, and I'm sure that it has some action script. I do ctrl+enter and it runs, it does stuff, but I can't find the code, I don't see any frame with the letter 'a' on it, where could it be ?
How to find it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of flash is it? Maybe the code is in a seperate file? If you're using flash cs3 or cs4, you should check the properties of the stage (Document) and under the tab Publish check if something is entered in Class.

Comment: nothing is entered in the class, and i tried to click on it and it tells me that i should target to as3 in order to do that, but still i found the as files in a folder near the fla, though i don't know how do they connect

Comment: actually there are more than one .as files used for that fla

Comment: could be that the movie clips in the library use these as files as classes. In the library you would see this stuff in the properties, or if you expand the library, I think one of the columns show this.

if that fail, use search to find any instances of #import

Answer (score 2):

It could be coded through the document class, or have the code in the movie clips.

I'm assuming it's the former, so check in the properties panel (when you have nothing selected and are in root) if it refers to an external as file.

Answer (score 2):

The actionscript code could be in multiple frames in the fla file.

It's good practice to put actionscript in an external .as file however it's also just as common to put the actionscript right into a movie clip.

Have a check through some clips by using the properties panel at the bottom to find out if the actionscript code is there.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find the code would be to use the Movie Explorer, under 'Windows'. If you don't find it there, try publishing in debug mode. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Adobe Flash CS5.5.

If you go to `Window->Actions` (or press alt+F9), you can see the "main code" of the timeline. In my case, all that does is instantiate another class.

The other ActionScript sources are included in the project's build path. Go to `File->Publish Settings` and click the little wrench next to Script:ActionScript 3.0. Then select the Source Path tab. Here you can see which source files are included in the project.

Hope that helps.